# Unable to get table DDL from Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-schema, ddl

I've tried to generate table DDL using SQLDeveloper, but after 3 seconds I get disconnect information:

```
"Your database connection has been reset. Any pending transactions or sessions state has been lost"
```

Same issue appears with using SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl and quick DDL export to file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does your user have permissions to do this? is there an ORA error showing?

Comment: Does the error occur when using SQL*Plus?  What version of SQLDev are you using?  I see several google results that are similar to this for SQLDev 3.2, so you may just need to upgrade your SQLDev (current version is 4.1.3) from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: Yes, I have permisions, no ORA shown. I also have the latest sql developer.

Comment: check the alert log for ORA-600's. we're making calls to DBMS_METADATA to generate the DDL. Can you run that as a query in the worksheet to see if the same thing happens there?  Does this happen for ALL tables, or just one?